# Can I build one or more c# projects in a Visual Studio 2017 solution with an older version of Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, version

I am switching to Visual Studio 2017 and I have a solution with about 45 projects.

When I build, the program fails at runtime with a typeref error.

If I compile one of the projects with Visual Studio 2015, the runtime error goes away.

Is there a way to specify the version of Visual Studio to use for a C# project?

Thanks, Allen

Comment: most of the upgraded versions of Visual Studio if not all of them, usually have and or give you an option to backup / save the current project prior to it running the conversion / compatibility for you.. have you tried it yet? also make sure you have the legacy .net versions on the machine you are wanting to convert the project to. have you tried google searching for documentation on converting projects over to newer version..?

Comment: Thanks for those suggestions.  I will give them a try.  Your suggestions are really appreciated!